# Matching the index of username and index of password in java

Tags: java

I want to match the username "carl" to the password "0001", as well as the other elements, but it's not working. Can anyone explain me how to match each elements of "username" to the elements of "password"? Thank you very much!
This is my code:

```
class log{
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String [] username ={"carl", "may", "joseph", "oliver", "ashley"};
    String []password={"0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0005"};

    public void login() throws IOException{
    System.out.print("\nUSERNAME: ");
    uname=br.readLine();
    System.out.print("PASSWORD: ");
    pword=br.readLine();

    for (j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
         if (username[j].equals(password[j])) {
           uname=username[j];
           pword=password[j];
    }          
}
while((!uname.equals(password[j]))&&(!pword.equals(username[j]))){
    System.out.println("Invalid username/password.");
    System.out.print("\nUSERNAME: ");
    uname=br.readLine();
    System.out.print("PASSWORD: ");
    pword=br.readLine();
}

public void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
       log b=new log();
       b.login();
}
```

Comment: This is called *parallel arrays* and is a very bad pattern. Instead of using multiple arrays, have a `class User` with the name and password as fields. This will make your logic much simpler and easier to debug.

Comment: How can be *carl* equals to *0001*? In your if condition you have to compare so *username[j].equals(uname) && passwords[j].equals(pword)*.

Comment: The people who put -1 for the question. I think the question is clear. And don't forget that your start in programing was something like this. Just be cooperative.

Comment: ok noted! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OOP (Object Oriented Programming) to make it easier in sovling your problem:

Here is my sample solution:

**User class:**

```
class User {

private String username;
private String password;

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    User user2 = (User) o;
    if (this.username.equals(user2.getUsername()) && this.password.equals(user2.getPassword()))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

}

**Login class:**

```
public class Login {


private User[] users = new User[]{
        new User("carl", "0001"),
        new User("may", "0002"),
        new User("joseph", "0003"),
        new User("oliver", "0004"),
        new User("ashley", "0005"),
};


public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("\nUSERNAME: ");
    String uname = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("PASSWORD: ");
    String pword = br.readLine();


    boolean success = new Login().login(new User(uname, pword));
    if (success)
        System.out.println("The user account is valid, login");
    else
        System.out.println("The username and/or password is invalid.");


}

public boolean login(User user) {
    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].equals(user))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello! It's been years since I wrote my rubbish code (those are the times that I don't know how to use OOP and just starting to code using Java) and this year I am taking the time to practice Java again (as I shifted my career from QA to dev). Thank you so much Abdulhamid Dhaiban for the kind words! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your method in following way

```
public void login() throws IOException {
    System.out.print("\nUSERNAME: ");
    uname = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("PASSWORD: ");
    pword = br.readLine();

    while (!isValid(uname, pword)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid username/password.");
        System.out.print("\nUSERNAME: ");
        uname = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("PASSWORD: ");
        pword = br.readLine();
    }
}
//checks if the entered username and password are correct
public boolean isValid(String uname, String pword) {
    for (int j = 0; j <username.length; j++) {
        if (username[j].equals(uname)) {
            if (!password[j].equals(pword))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it it better when you work with an extra Class `User`.

The class looks like this:

```
class User {
     private String name;
     private String pw;
     public User (String name, String pw) {
         this.name = name;
         this.pw = pw;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getPw() {
        return this.pw;
    }
}
```

In your program logic you have a list with all users:

```
ArrayList<User> userList
```

Now you have change the login algorithm:

```
class log{
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ArrayList<User> userList = ...; //Here you have to add all users first

    boolean loginCheck = false;
    while(loginCheck == false) {
        System.out.print("\nUSERNAME: ");
        uname = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("PASSWORD: ");
        pword = br.readLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            if (userList.get(i).getName.equals(uname) && userList.get(i).getPw.equals(pword)) {
                loginCheck = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }            
}    

public void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
       log b=new log();
       b.login();
}
```

You can make the algorithm faster if you change the check for the user input into this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            if (userList.get(i).getName.equals(uname)) {
                if (userList.get(i).getPw.equals(pword)) {
                    loginCheck = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    break;
                }                
            }
}
```